# How to change a file's default program

Tags: .desktop, default-programs

I accidentally set a .desktop file to always open in kate, and meant to execute it. How do I change the default program?

Sorry if this has been asked before or is an easy fix, I am fairly new to linux, and am having a couple difficulties finding my way around.

Comment: what Desktop Are you using? KDE?

Comment: KDE is correct.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right Click
2. Properties
3. Open With
4. Found the app you want

BTW I found a site for you which is pretty helpful for newbies to ubuntu, [check it out](http://google.com)

Comment: Wow, that's an amazing site!

Comment: i like it so much :p anyways, did that solved the issue?

Comment: @biozalp are you a wizard? #sarcasm